# Build Settings Base SDK 10.9

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have OS X 10.9 and Xcode 5 installed but I'm not able set `Base SDK` to `OS X 10.9` while I only have `OS X 10.8` in the select box under `Build Settings > Base SDK`. Do I'm missing something?

Comment: Which Xcode version do you have? The 10.9 SDK for Mavericks was added in Xcode 5.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(From above comment:)* The 10.9 SDK for Mavericks was added in Xcode 5.0.1.